# Exsitence of stationary distribution for M/M/1 with non-homogeneous poisson arrival rate

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, ergodic-theory, queueing-theory, steady-state

Consider an M/M/1 queue where arrivals occur at rate $\lambda(t)$ according to a Poisson process at time $t$ and move the process from state $i$ to $i+1$, and service times have an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\mu$. Assume $\lambda(t) < \mu, \forall t \geq 0$. I am wondering if we can upper bound the $\lambda(t)$ by $\lambda$ and show the stationary distribution of the queue with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$ exists, can we say the stationary distribution of the original system (i.e. a system with arrival rate $\lambda(t)$ and service rate $\mu$) exists?

---

I did not find any book about the ergodic theory of the Markov Chain with a non-homogeneous Poisson process. I am quite confused about it.

Comment: In order to have some kind of stationary distribution, it would be essential for $\lambda(t)$ to itself be stationary in some sense.  You can't get a stationary distribution when $\lambda(t)$ is just an arbitrary bounded function.

Comment: Thanks, @RJTK. $\lambda(t)$ is a piecewise constant function. But what do you mean "\lambda(t) is stationary"?

Comment: Say $\lambda(t)$ is a continuous time markov chain on the state $\{\lambda_0, \lambda_1\}$, if this is the input to the queue, then the system should have some stationary distribution which depends on the stationary distribution of the CTMC $\lambda(t)$.  On the other hand, say $\lambda(t) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\text{sin}(\pi t)$, how could the distribution of the queue converge?